# Connecting QnA maker with the webapp Bot service of azure

Tags: azure-bot-service

I have created the Knowledge base in the QnA maker and tested it as well. It is working fine. But while creating the Web app bot service in Azure portal I selected Basic Bot for which it asked for a Luis Account. I did not have any but there was a provision to create new and I did so. Post which the bot service was deployed successfully.

The problem is I am not able to connect it to the QnA maker knowledge base. The fields like QnAKnowledgebaseId, QnAAuthKey, and the QnAEndpointHostName are not at all present under application settings where I can input the values. I tried to add an additional application string with the details but still it did not work. My knowledgebase is ready but the bot service does not work with it. Clearly you can see in the images there is no fields where I can put my QnA knowledgebase configurations

Bot application setting:

[image: Bot application setting]

Application setting:

[image: Application setting]

Comment: Integrating additional cognitive services like QnA Maker with a bot is not quite as simple as adding a QnA key to your bot's configuration. The knowledge base details won't do anything unless the bot is programmed to use them. Can you let us know what language your bot code is written in?

Comment: I have successfully established connection now.Could you please let me know if there is a scope to change the look of the azure bot if yes which source code file do I need to make the changes in?

Comment: If your original issue has been resolved, would you please post your resolution as an answer and post a new question if you're encountering new problems?

Answer (score 0):

The bot service can be integrated with the QnA maker just through portal itself.I created the Bot service directly from the QnA maker and it picked up the Details of the QnA maker automatically.The webapp bot is up and running answering the questions as per the repo in the QnA Maker